# Turn physics on and off on specific object

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can i turn on and off the "physics.addBody" on my "bar" object?

If i try:

```
physics.pause(bar, "static", {density=.1, bounce=.5, friction=.2,filter=barCosllisionFilter } )
```

All physics pause

bar object:

```
bar = display.newSprite( BARimageSheet, BARsequenceData1)
bar.x = display.contentWidth/2
bar.y = display.contentHeight/2
bar:play()
bar.collided = true
bar.name = "bar"
bar.gravityScale = 0.0 
physics.addBody(bar, "static", {density=.0, bounce=.5, friction=.2,filter=barCosllisionFilter } )           
bar.isVisible = true-- false
bar.isFixedRotation=true
screenGroup:insert(bar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to turn it off:

```
--change the bar body's active state to false
bar.isBodyActive = false
```

To turn it on again, just set the property back to true.